# Ontouchstart event does not fire after removeChild

Tags: javascript, ipad, html

I found a problem trying to code JavaScript for iPad. I haven't tested this on other HTML5 touch browsers, so I don't know if this is an iPad / Mobile Safari bug or something more general.

The problem is that if an object has an ontouchstart event listener attached, it initially works fine, but after I remove it from its parent container and add it again, it stops working.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = clickBtn;
        document.getElementById("touch").ontouchstart = touchDiv;
    }

    function clickBtn(e) {
        var cnt = document.getElementById("container");
        var tdv = document.getElementById("touch");
        cnt.removeChild(tdv);
        cnt.appendChild(tdv);
    }

    function touchDiv(e) {
        var sp = document.getElementById("sp");         
        sp.innerHTML += "*";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=container>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;" id="touch">Touch this</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Test</button>
<span id=sp></span>
</body>
</html>
```

(For convenience, I put it also here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8100013/test.html.) If you touch the red square on iPad, a "*" is added to the text next to the button to show that the touchstart event fired. Pushing the button removes the red square from its parent container and adds it again. After that, at least on my iPad, the "*" characters no longer get added so it seems the touchstart doesn't fire.

Does anyone know what's going on? I admit I'm new to Javascript/HTML5 so I could be missing something obvious, but in the same situation on a PC with a mouse, the mousedown event works fine after removal and re-insertion of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parent of a dom element also removes the events attached, *all* of them. But I think if instead of `.removeChild`, you `document.body.appendChild`, it wouldn't happen.

Comment: I tested this now. If I replace "cnt.removeChild(tdv);" with "document.body.appendChild(tdv);" it still works the same on iPad.